# TensorFlowJs | tf.loadLayersModel Not Working

Tags: tensorflow.js

Using sample code from the following link:
https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadLayersModel

Checking the localstorage of Chrome I do see 'my-model-1' there, so it is getting saved but not loaded back into loadedModel. I have verified localstorage in Chrome and IE and 'my-model-1' is there in both browsers. IE doesn't throw an error, while Chrome does throw the error.

```
const model = tf.sequential({layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [3]})]});
model.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();
const saveResults = model.save('localstorage://my-model-1');
const loadedModel = tf.loadLayersModel('localstorage://my-model-1');
loadedModel.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();
```

Expected loadedModel.predict to work and instead getting loadedModel.predict is not a function error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

[`tf.loadLayersModel`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/#loadLayersModel) returns a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which resolves to the model. The same is also true for `model.save`.

**Solution**

You need to either use [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) or [`.then`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) to wait until the Promise is resolved. Here is your code with the correct `await` statements:

```js
(async () => {
  const model = tf.sequential({layers: [tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [3]})]});
  model.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();
  const saveResults = await model.save('localstorage://my-model-1');
  const loadedModel = await tf.loadLayersModel('localstorage://my-model-1');
  loadedModel.predict(tf.ones([1, 3])).print();
})();
```

The code is executed in an `async` function as only here it is allowed to use the `await` keyword.

Comment: I have the same problem and i actually i already had the await move, i tried this and got: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: tf.loadLayersModel is not a function